# How to prolong a threading.Timer's duration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

How do you dynamically update and prolong the duration of an existing `threading.Timer` instance, so that it extends its "life" by *n* seconds when I call the `prolong` method?

Here's the code I've been testing, with errors and effects as comments behind each line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from threading import Timer # v3.9.0

def prolong(self, n):
    # print(self.finished) # AttributeError: type object 'Timer' has no attribute 'finished'
    # print(self.interval) # AttributeError: type object 'Timer' has no attribute 'interval'
    self.interval = n + 0.1 # assigns the number, but doesn't prolong anything...
    print("p: self.interval:", self.interval) # 3.1
    a.interval = n + 0.2 # updates the attribute, but doesn't change the actual duration...
    print("p: a.interval:", a.interval) # 3.2
    # a.finished.wait(n + 0.3) # TypeError: 'float' object is not callable - bcos locked?
    print("p: a.finished.wait #1:", a.finished.wait) # 3.5 
    # print("p: a.finished.wait #1.1:", a.finished.wait) # <bound method Event.wait of <threading.Event object at 0x000001754603FC88>>

Timer.prolong = classmethod(prolong)

def test_it():
    print ("t: updated interval:", a.interval) # 3.2

def update_it(interval):
    # a = Timer(3.4, test_it) # affects a.finished.wait #1.1 (starts another thread?)
    a.finished.wait = 3.5 # does nothing
    print("u: a.finished.wait #2:", a.finished.wait) # 3.5
    a.finished._cond.wait = 3.6 # does nothing
    # a.finished.wait(3.7) # TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
    a.interval = 3.8 # does nothing
    a.prolong(interval)

# make a test that lasts 2 seconds
a = Timer(2.0, test_it) 
a.start()

# update `a` after 1.0 second and prolong it to 3.0 seconds (should run for approx 4 seconds total)## Heading ##
interval = 3.0
b = Timer(1.0, update_it, [interval]) 
b.start()
# [Finished in 2.2s]
```

I'm basically flailing in the dark. I've tried to extend the object by 3.0 seconds with various attempts, with some tenth of a second added in the method as an "id" to check whether it affected anything... I've been commenting out "bad" or failing lines as I find them, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

In an older version of the class I was able to somewhat access the `wait` timer through the `finished` method, which used to hold an event, but now it just raises an `AttributeError`.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I prolong the "life" of `a`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only way to prolong a `Timer` would be to call `.cancel()` on it, and then create a new `Timer` with an updated duration.  However, this is a fairly simple class - it wouldn't be much work to duplicate it, and add your desired functionality.  One approach would be to have a queue of durations, that your `.prolong()` method appends to; the `.run()` method would do an `Event.wait()` for each of these durations, until it finally empties the queue.

Comment: I already have a fully working "cancel" version like that, but it feels like a personal failure to not be able to prolong the timer directly. I'm not sure about a stack version, when the counter exists in memory somewhere. I really want to learn how to fetch it, in order to truly understand the `threading` class.